# Make it easy to unselect all percentile tags

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I have a lot of top-percentile tags (75+ "top 10%"; 25+ "top 20%"). It's useless to display the majority of them, so I cull most of them out.

Unfortunately, the site sometimes forgets my selections, and I have to start curating the list again. It would be nice if I don't have to manually click 100 checkboxes before I begin.